# Visual Studio Win32 Project Error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a new Win32 Console Application in Visual Studio 2015 (Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1) on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS and I keep getting the following error:

[image]

When I go to the Platforms directory I notice that there is no Win32 subdirectory but there are directories that seem like they would be useful for a 64 bit platform (see screenshot below). My question is how can/should I resolve this so that I can create Win32 Console applications in Visual Studio on my Windows 7 computer? Do I need to install something that will create the necessary Win32 subdirectory, do I need to configure Visual Studio to use a different directory in the Import declaration, do I need to use a different version of Visual Studio, or something else? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried repairing your VS installation?

Comment: I am embarrassed to admit that that seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks! FYI, my repair didn't complete successfully but it did seem to get through that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zaid for pointing out the simple solution of doing a repair on my VS installation. Leaving this up here in case it helps anyone else out.